# Remeber me member all users even if they do not want to be remembered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Remember me is not working properly.

How I want it to work -> at the time of login if the user checks the remember me checkbox app should remember it otherwise it does not need to remember the user.

but currently, even if the user does not checks the remember me checkbox it remember it.

Application Controller:

```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :logged_in_user, :current_user?, :forget

  before_action :set_cache_buster

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
       user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end


  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = 'Please log in.'
      redirect_to new_sessions_path
    end
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  private

  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
  end
end
```

Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

  def create
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me] == 1
        log_in user
        token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        user.auth_token = token
        cookies.permanent.signed[:auth_token] = token
        redirect_to user
  else
       log_in user
       user.auth_token = nil
       cookies[:auth_token] = nil
       redirect_to user
  end


     else
       flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
       render 'new'
     end
   end

   def destroy
       @current_user = nil
       cookies[:auth_token] = nil
       reset_session
       redirect_to root_path
   end

end
```

What i tried:

```
  def create
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])

       if params[:remember_me] == 1
         log_in user
         token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
         user.auth_token = token
         cookies.permanent.signed[:auth_token] = token
         redirect_to user
      else
        # log_in user
         user.auth_token = nil
         cookies[:auth_token] = nil
         redirect_to user
      end

     else
       flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
       render 'new'
     end
   end
```

I commented the **login user** line in above code. What was it not to let 
the user login in check box is not ticked. It worked. but then ...i commented log_in line if portion of code ...

```
   if params[:remember_me] == 1
          #   log_in user
             token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
             user.auth_token = token
             cookies.permanent.signed[:auth_token] = token
             redirect_to user
          else
```

It user should not have let user login if checkbox is ticked but it did let user login.

For some reason, i think 'if' in sessions controller never works.

session#new -- login page --

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7" style="text-align: center;">
    <h2><b>Log In</b></h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">
    <%= form_with url: sessions_path do |form| %>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :email %>
          <%= form.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :password %>
          <%= form.text_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
          <%= form.label :"remember_me" %>
          <%= form.check_box :remember_me %>
      </div>

     <%= form.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error message is clear. In the `create` action of your `SessionsController`, you call `if remember_me == 1`, but you don't have a `remember_me` method. Thus, `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'remember_me' for #)`.  You need to create the method.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying. but I m struct at this point from the past few days. There is no source of help. Do you know where does ruby/rails community help forums are? I mean any community of rails expert knows who can to build a simple remember me functionality?

Comment: From the login page remember is passed in params. I don't there is a need to create a function for reading value of a variable. In User model, i wrote a line attr_accesible: remember_me and that error disappeared.  I have updated my code, it is still not working. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Yes, there was ** (:rememeber_me <> :remember_me) ** before ,i had made some spelling mistake(s). You were right, you are right.

Comment: {"authenticity_token"=>"nVpQf6FLoPGdu6RVaTUokaKEsnG9dUN6ubl51T4gIzswKY64OBlIkJu3B1ngbPPS2XuZRLl/uTb6k9xscGk+6Q==", "email"=>"sneha@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0", "commit"=>"Login"}

Comment: Not sure what that last comment is meant to say. Or what your situation is now that you've fixed typos.

Comment: i wrote 'rememeber_me' at 2 places. I had corrected one earlier, i corrected when you ponted out. typos are fixed now.